# Weird "Parsing error: Unexpected token" in React with TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, function, object

I have this helper function, which was working fine when written in JavaScript. But when I added TypeScript, weird things started to happen. That is a file with a function:

```
interface Toy {
  setId: string;
  name: string;
  year: number;
  themeId: number;
  themeName: string;
  subthemeId: number;
  subthemeName: string;
  parts: number;
  imageUrl: string;
  brandName: string;
}
enum SortBy {
  NameAsc = 'name-asc',
  NameDsc = 'name-dsc',
  PartsAsc = 'parts-asc',
  PartsDsc = 'parts-dsc',
  YearAsc = 'year-asc',
  YearDsc = 'year-dsc'
}
type Property = 'name' | 'parts' | 'year';
type Type = 'asc' | 'dsc';
type SortParams = [Property, Type];

const sortToys = (_toys: Toy[], sortBy: SortBy): any => {
  const toys = _toys.sort((toy1, toy2) => {
    const [property, type] = <SortParams>sortBy.split('-');
    const properties = {
      toy1: toy1[property],
      toy2: toy2[property]
    };
    if (properties.toy1 > properties.toy2) {
      return type === 'asc' ? 1 : -1;
    } else if (properties.toy1 < properties.toy2) {
      return type === 'asc' ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
  const pages = [];
  while (toys.length) {
    pages.push(toys.splice(0, 30));
  }
  return pages;
};

export default sortToys;
```

And this is an error I get when trying to build the project:

```
src\utils\helpers\filterToys.ts
  Line 12:11:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}"      

  10 |     const [property, type] = <SortParams>sortBy.split('-');
  11 |     const properties = {
> 12 |       toy1: toy1[property],
     |           ^
  13 |       toy2: toy2[property]
  14 |     };
  15 |     if (
```

I understand there is no problem with the object itself, but probably something going on around. I can't figure it out, maybe someone sees something odd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because TS is unsure whether you use JSX or not.

Just try to avoid `<Type>variable` notation.

If you want to use type assertion, just use `as` operator.

```js
interface Toy {
  setId: string;
  name: string;
  year: number;
  themeId: number;
  themeName: string;
  subthemeId: number;
  subthemeName: string;
  parts: number;
  imageUrl: string;
  brandName: string;
}
enum SortBy {
  NameAsc = 'name-asc',
  NameDsc = 'name-dsc',
  PartsAsc = 'parts-asc',
  PartsDsc = 'parts-dsc',
  YearAsc = 'year-asc',
  YearDsc = 'year-dsc'
}
type Property = 'name' | 'parts' | 'year';
type Type = 'asc' | 'dsc';
type SortParams = [Property, Type];

const sortToys = (_toys: Toy[], sortBy: SortBy): any => {
  const toys = _toys.sort((toy1, toy2) => {
    const [property, type] = sortBy.split('-') as SortParams; // fixed
    const properties = {
      toy1: toy1[property],
      toy2: toy2[property]
    };
    if (properties.toy1 > properties.toy2) {
      return type === 'asc' ? 1 : -1;
    } else if (properties.toy1 < properties.toy2) {
      return type === 'asc' ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
  const pages = [];
  while (toys.length) {
    pages.push(toys.splice(0, 30));
  }
  return pages;
};

export default sortToys;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoHsCeyDeAoZZAZwjAEkATALmLClAHMBuA5EOAWwhqLsZcKYIcKDRABXDgCNoA5GAAWELpTGSZUOYuUQAcp2616IZqyLip2ldTbrZZi1b0GefE3IAOIsETXT7hMAccAwQAKpQADauxqaEUlBwIBT6XDH8eAC%20eBASHMgAyuhQYABC2PiEqRAAgkQIyAC8yADk7FwAtHD1LQA0rNUAIvVNre0QHRQ9-YQACt5EdQ3NLV4lRF3TrPPrw8utaz6TW4QAmsJQS6MtQiKbCH2s5yJ717dQxw9ZeGCYHiizKDof4lbArcYtZAAHwOC0hMJuFxaLF%20-zQfxQK26D2hrSmDxRGMKxTAO04RFGAG1AcDoL9euj-gBdFh4BDoEC8YgkjCYCnNAAUAH0wFhfGgsJSmQyiCTyjQiiVygBKGhJMEAPlwrHZnLA8jFoxFYoAdLKSgKBaLMABGBnWgBMyqaWsqhGQuq5lI8QJB9PkGKZo3NZUwZo8kWAYAFLQ6LWd3WJJTJHCIckInv1PtpJWAEH52vd7utNpoJe9vrpmGlrCLjrLWAdFZzvyZteQmXTyGAMGQAuzfrzRBNJeQWoHdKHI8bzrdRagpHEUBAAbRjXXrWxkIA-MgbcgaB0bV3MsgIJESN3e-3K7n89PbcgADzICd34eO2ftwgLsBLleopiG4tFuyC7keB57ie7a-v%20yAAAxyJkypyJmr4hPmVIsqwADuCjAJEKBWqahEmIoX5Fl4oTDh44hEAoxF8uGkZIAK8EMgAzPByooaw2Q-ouy7odRLCdngOQAB4eCSyAUBA8DiJE%20ohryaZAA)

Comment: I tried that, but the I get "Parsing error: Missing semicolon" error pointed at "as"

Comment: I have added playground link. It works as expected

Comment: Ok, will try playing around with tsconfig file, maybe that's the issue. Thanks :)

Comment: Uhh, I gave up, can't spend another day on this... I removed "as SortBy" and added //@ts-ignore comments above toy1: (...) and toy2: (...). Probably a problem with eslint or parser. If anoyne else has similiar problem in the future, I'd be very thankful for the answer :)

Comment: Do you have TS compiler error or eslint error?